# Not a git repository although git init was typed before git remote and repository URL was entered in the remote command

Tags: github, mingw-w64, git-clone, git-pull, git-remote

My friend is working on a Pokemon Emerald ROM Hack, and he wanted to merge into the Dynamic Overworld System as part of it. However, git remote was unsuccessful.

- He typed `git init` before remoting
- He put in the repository URL;
  `git remote add ExpoSeed https://github.com/ExpoSeed/pokeemerald.git`
- He cloned into the pret's pokeemerald GitHub: https://github.com/pret/pokeemerald and the rh's pokeemerald expansion Github: https://github.com/rh-hideout/pokeemerald-expansion (because the people at the Pokecommunity Discord Server suggested me to tell him to do so)
- He went into his pokeemerald folder to enter his command
  `MINGW46 ~/Desktop/decomps/pokeemerald $ git remote add ExpoSeed https://github.com/ExpoSeed/pokeemerald.git`

But despite doing all these, he still got:

`fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /cygdrive) Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`
If there is a problem with his computer, how could he fix it?